# divide the count with the population to create incidence maps in crossfilter dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm creating a map with dc.js to display some diseases per province.
I managed to create a map with the total `count` by using this dimension and group:

```
,provinceDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.province; })
,provinceGroup = provinceDimension.group()
```

where d.province is defined like this:

```
    switch (d.NUTS2) {
        case 10: d.province = "Brussels"; break;
        case 21: d.province = "Antwerp"; break;
        case 22: d.province = "Limburg"; break;
        case 23: d.province = "East Flanders"; break;
        case 24: d.province = "Flemish Brabant"; break;
        case 25: d.province = "West Flanders"; break;
        case 31: d.province = "Walloon Brabant"; break;
        case 32: d.province = "Hainaut"; break;
        case 33: d.province = "Liege"; break;
        case 34: d.province = "Luxembourg"; break;
        case 35: d.province = "Namur"; break;
        default: d.province = "UNK";
    };
```

How do you create a dimension and group to display the incidence (`=count *100000 /population`) instead of the `count`?

I think I need to modify the group and use reduce functions to achieve this but my understanding of groups is very limited for the moment.

Here's what I have tried so far without any luck

```
    ,provinceGroup = provinceDimension.group().reduce(reduceAddIncidence('province'), reduceRemoveIncidence('province'), reduceInitIncidence)

function reduceAddIncidence(attr) {
  return function(p,v) {
    ++p.count
    switch (v['province']) {
        case "Brussels": p.incidence = p.count*100000/1111; break;
        case "Antwerp": p.incidence = p.count*100000/2222; break;
        case "Limburg": p.incidence = p.count*100000/3333; break;
        case "East Flanders": p.incidence = p.count*100000/4444; break;
        case "Flemish Brabant": p.incidence = p.count*100000/5555; break;
        case "West Flanders": p.incidence = p.count*100000/6666; break;
        case "Walloon Brabant": p.incidence = p.count*100000/7777; break;
        case "Hainaut": p.incidence = p.count*100000/8888; break;
        case "Liege": p.incidence = p.count*100000/9999; break;
        case "Luxembourg": p.incidence = p.count*100000/1010; break;
        case "Namur": p.incidence = p.count*100000/1111; break;
        case "UNK": p.incidence = p.count*100000/1212; break;
    };
    return p;
  };
}
function reduceRemoveIncidence(attr) {
  return function(p,v) {
    --p.count
    switch (v['province']) {
        case "Brussels": p.incidence = p.count*100000/1111; break;
        case "Antwerp": p.incidence = p.count*100000/2222; break;
        case "Limburg": p.incidence = p.count*100000/3333; break;
        case "East Flanders": p.incidence = p.count*100000/4444; break;
        case "Flemish Brabant": p.incidence = p.count*100000/5555; break;
        case "West Flanders": p.incidence = p.count*100000/6666; break;
        case "Walloon Brabant": p.incidence = p.count*100000/7777; break;
        case "Hainaut": p.incidence = p.count*100000/8888; break;
        case "Liege": p.incidence = p.count*100000/9999; break;
        case "Luxembourg": p.incidence = p.count*100000/1010; break;
        case "Namur": p.incidence = p.count*100000/1111; break;
        case "UNK": p.incidence = p.count*100000/1212; break;
    };
    return p;
  };
}
function reduceInitIncidence() {
  return {count:0, sums:0, incidence:0};
}
```

> 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444... represent the population here

Many thanks!

------EDIT------

Here is the map code I use

```
mapChart
    .width(width3)
    .height(height3)
    .dimension(provinceDimension) // set crossfilter dimension, dimension key should match the name retrieved in geo json layer
    .group(provinceGroup) // set crossfilter group
    .transitionDuration(200)
    .projection(d3.geo.mercator()
        .translate([width3/2,height3/2])
        .center([-1.481, 0.01])
        .scale(3500*width3)
    )
    .overlayGeoJson(geojson.features, 'province', function(d) {
        return d.properties.name;
    })
    .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#FFE1CC","#FFD5B7","#FFC9A3","#FFBD8E","#FFB17A","#FFA566","#FF9951","#FF8D3D","#FF8128","#FF7514","#FF6900"]))
    .title(function(d) {
        return d.key + ' : ' + d.value ;
    })
    ;
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, although I would simplify it by creating a population map outside your reduce functions like `var population = {Brussels: 1111, Antwerp: 2222, ...}` and using it inside your reduce functions like so: `p.incidence = p.count*100000/population[p.province];` What results are you getting? NaNs?

Comment: I think it is working too. But I never specified that the map graph should use p.incidence. (I don't see how the map will know to use p.count or p.sums or p.incidence), I'll add the chart code in my question.

Comment: You should use the valueAccessor for that. I'd be surprised if it works at all without that.